# fillField method in codeception not working throwing DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

Tags: codeception

$I->fillField("username", "test");

On running the acceptance test, get the following error:

Sorry, I couldn't fill field "username","test":
ErrorException: DOMXPath::query(): Invalid expression

the input element is inside a form. I tried adding id to the input and also accessing the element using inpu..but all returned the same error. "see" method is working..but not fillField or seeInField.

Comment: Same probleme. I made a composer update today

Comment: See: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/1035 && https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/10987

Answer (score 2):

You have to tell codeception what element it's looking for.

if username is an id do:

```
$I->fillField("#username", "test");
```

and if a class do:

```
$I->fillField(".username", "test");
```

or enter the xpath of the element: (eg. search field on google.com)

```
$I->fillfield('//*[@id="gbqfq"]','my search text test');
```